# When i click on my buttons in my app that i have built using Swift and xcode they dont work

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

Ive added some buttons to a profile page on my app using swift but when i run my app they don't work. They appear on the page but they don't allow the user to click them and i don't know why this is my code that i am using:

in my profileHeader Class:

```
let editProfileFollowButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setTitle("Edit Profile", for: .normal)
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    button.layer.borderWidth = 1
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
    button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleEditProfileFollowButton), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()

@objc func handleEditProfileFollowButton() {
    delegate?.handleEditFollowTapped(for: self)
}
```

in my profileVC:

```
func handleEditFollowTapped(for header: ProfileHeader) {
       print("handle edit follow tapped")
   }
```

so when the button is pressed its supposed to print "handle edit follow tapped" but it does nothing and im not sure why.

Even if i do it in the same class like this:

```
let editProfileFollowButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setTitle("Edit Profile", for: .normal)
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    button.layer.borderWidth = 1
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
    button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleEditProfileFollowButton), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()

@objc func handleEditProfileFollowButton() {
    print("handle edit follow tapped")
}
```

it doesnt work.

this is how i display the button:

```
addSubview(editProfileFollowButton)
editProfileFollowButton.anchor(top: profileBanner.bottomAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 12, paddingLeft: 75, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 75, width: 0, height: 30)
```

this is what it looks like when it is displayed:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `editProfileFollowButton` lazily because when you're declaring the `editProfileFollowButton` self (ProfileHeader class in your case) is still not available. Here's how

Modify this:

```
let editProfileFollowButton: UIButton = {
```

To this:

```
lazy var editProfileFollowButton: UIButton = {
```

Comment: i changed it to the above and it didnt make any difference